# É possível adicionar propriedades ao arquivo css criado pelo build do angular?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Meu build do angular gera uma adição de folha de estilo no no index.html da seguinte forma:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-2.css">
```

Tem como configurá-lo para adicionar mais propriedades e deixá-lo como o exemplo abaixo?

```
<link rel="dx-theme" href="style-1.css" data-active="false">
<link rel="dx-theme" href="style-2.css" data-active="false">
```

meu angular.json está assim:

```
"extractCss": true,
"styles": [
   {input: "src/styles.scss", "bundleName": "style-1"},
   {input: "src/styles2.scss", "bundleName": "style-2"}  
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode customizar toda build do AngularCLI usando a [API de Builders](https://angular.io/guide/cli-builder), e para ficar ainda mais fácil você pode usar o [ngx-build-plus](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus), que é um projeto da comunidade que te deixa customizar diretamente o arquivo de configuração do Webpack.

Para a customização que está pedindo especificamente, acho que [essa issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/240) pode ajudar sobre como incluir atributos na tag style.

Comment: Muito obrigado, e grato pela ajuda. Eu não conhecia o ngx-build-plus. Meu deu uma enorme ajuda. Pelo direcionamento da issue cheguei a uma conclusão. Posso adicionar a propriedade "inject": false para não adicionar os arquivos e incluí-los manualmente no index html com as propriedades que preciso.